# Setting up a FHIR server

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I'm trying to set up a little server on my localhost (proof of concept-ish) environment using asp.net core (c#) but keep getting the same error when I visit the 'get' route:

```
FormatException: Cannot determine type of resource to create from json input data. Is there a 'resourceType' member present? (at path 'line 1, pos 1')
```

Here's my code:

```
[Route("Patient/rvrbk")]
public Patient ServeClient()
{
    Patient patient = new Patient();

    patient.Id = "1";
    patient.Gender = AdministrativeGender.Male;
    patient.Name = new List<HumanName> { new HumanName { Family = "Verbeek", Given = new List<string> { "Rik" }, Suffix = new List<string> { "The Small" } } };
    patient.BirthDate = "2004-03-10";
    patient.Active = true;

    return patient;
}

[Route("get")]
public Patient GetClient()
{
    FhirClient client = new FhirClient("http://localhost:54240/");

    var patient = client.Read<Patient>("Patient/rvrbk");

    return patient;
}
```

I've tried to set the resourceType on the patient object but that produces an error since it's readonly. I'm sure I'm missing something trivial but can't figure out what.

**EDIT**

After the answers provided by @AdrianoRepetti I came up with the following setup but ran into another error:

```
FhirOperationException: Operation was unsuccessful, and returned status OK. OperationOutcome: Overall result: FAILURE (1 errors and 0 warnings) [ERROR] (no details)(further diagnostics: Endpoint returned a body with contentType 'text/plain', while a valid FHIR xml/json body type was expected. Is this a FHIR endpoint?).
```

Code:

```
[Route("Patient/rvrbk")]
public string ServeClient()
{
    Patient patient = new Patient();

    patient.Id = "1";
    patient.Gender = AdministrativeGender.Male;
    patient.Name = new List<HumanName> { new HumanName { Family = "Verbeek", Given = new List<string> { "Rik" }, Suffix = new List<string> { "The Small" } } };
    patient.BirthDate = "2004-03-10";
    patient.Active = true;

    FhirJsonSerializer serializer = new FhirJsonSerializer();

    string json = serializer.SerializeToString(patient);

    return json;
}
```

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for your reply, I'm not exactly sure how to read your response, what do you mean with 'post BOTH the Name'? Can you supply some example code? I'm using the STU3 implementation. Maybe the Family property has some overloads?, the compiler was ok with this version.

Comment: You should ask to who wrote the FHIR implementation you're using but...an educated guess: deserializer needs to know exact object type to determine which class must be instantiated (given a list of `Base` should  instances be `Derived` or `AnotherDerived`?). Why this? Because `ServeClient()` returns a simple JSON object where `resourceType` member is not present. You can _instruct_ your JSON serializer to add it or - maybe - use the tools your FHIR implementation provides.

Comment: Yeah, this information is lost indeed, I try asking the author how to send this info to the client. I shall keep you informed.

Comment: See, for example, a proper writer: https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api/blob/master/src/Hl7.Fhir.Core/Serialization/JsonDomFhirWriter.cs. You can't simply return a default serialized JSON object.

Comment: Ok, I made some alterations in the code (see original post) but am getting the error 'FhirOperationException: Operation was unsuccessful, and returned status OK. OperationOutcome: Overall result: FAILURE (1 errors and 0 warnings) [ERROR] (no details)(further diagnostics: Endpoint returned a body with contentType 'text/plain', while a valid FHIR xml/json body type was expected. Is this a FHIR endpoint?).'

Comment: Error message is somehow explicative. Now you have (maybe) a valid JSON object but you're returning a `string` then ASP.NET MVC sets `Content-Type` to `text/plain` (which isn't a valid format for FHIR client). I'm not sure about what you're using server side but something like this: `return Content(json, "application/json");` Don't forget to change return type from `string` to `IActionResult`.

Comment: That said, this is a pretty verbose and error-prone approach because you have to write that boilerplate code in each function. You can set your JSON serializer or a specific media formatter for all WebAPI calls (and you can then revert to code in your first solution where you simply return `Patient`). Check MSDN for details about setting a custom JSON serializer (and deserializer!) or what media formatters are.

Comment: Yes I realize that, as I said, this is a proof of concept thingy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

My first problem was (as pointed out by @Adriano Repetti) that the client didn't know which object it was receiving, this was resolved by running the object trough the SerializeToString([object]) function which is provided by FhirJsonSerializer.

My next problem was that I was returning a string while the client expected 'application/json'. This was resolved by changing the returntype of the 'server' to JsonResult and parse the generated string to json with JObject.Parse([string]).

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Hl7.Fhir.Model;
using Hl7.Fhir.Rest;
using Hl7.Fhir.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace FIHR.Controllers
{
    [Route("")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Welkom op de FIHR API";
        }

        [Route("Patient/rvrbk")]
        public IActionResult ServeClient()
        {
            Patient patient = new Patient();

            patient.Id = "1";
            patient.Gender = AdministrativeGender.Male;
            patient.Name = new List<HumanName> { new HumanName { Family = "Verbeek", Given = new List<string> { "Rik" }, Suffix = new List<string> { "The Small" } } };
            patient.BirthDate = "2004-03-10";
            patient.Active = true;

            FhirJsonSerializer serializer = new FhirJsonSerializer();

            string jstring = serializer.SerializeToString(patient);

            return Content(jstring, "application/json");
        }

        [Route("get")]
        public Patient GetClient()
        {
            FhirClient client = new FhirClient("http://localhost:54240/"); // http://vonk.fire.ly

            Patient patient = client.Read<Patient>("Patient/rvrbk"); // Patient/example

            return patient;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, definitely you do not need to serialize then parse then serialize again just to set the `Content-Type` header. See latest [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768408/setting-up-a-fhir-server?noredirect=1#comment86559538_49768408)

Comment: I can't put 'jstring' directly trough the Json() return statement because it whines about the result being just text and I cant pass the Patient object directly into the JObject.parse method because it expects a string. Or am I understanding you wrongly?

Comment: See comment below the question. `return Content(jstring, "application/json")` (and change function prototype to `public IActionResult ServeClient()`. HOWEVER (I know I'm repetitive...) do not do this outside an experiment. To repeat this code in each method is not the way to go, you can instruct ASP.NET MVC (if it's what you're using) to use the JSON serializer you want (`FhirJsonSerializer` or an adapter object if its interface does not fit) and you will have the clean code of your first example.